# Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture - Test Questions?

Tags: design-patterns, poeaa

I'm doing course in "Software patterns and design" at the university and the book for the course is "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture - Fowler"

The test in on wednesday and the teacher doesn't have any past exams i can through to see what the test is going to look like.

Is someone that has taken a course from this book and has any test questions that i can run through before the test?

Comment: I would recommend implementing these patterns in a program and understanding practical purposes for them.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this unanswered question, so this might be an useless answer...

IIRC, the PoEAA book has some summary and overview sections that could be used as a trigger for yourself to answer in depth. I also think that the book describes some situations (as questions) and answers these with a description of which pattern to use and why.

But heck... You can probably answer this question best by your self by now?